# Trouble with Joins (SQL on Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I have a few tables:

[See them here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPEv8.png)

I need to get some data from them both. I must list all Computer Science Alumni from 2014 (from AlumnusDeg table), and include their name email and home phone number (from Alumnus table).

The following code returns the Computer Science Alumni from 2014:

```
SELECT * FROM AlumnusDeg 
WHERE DegreeName LIKE '%Computer Science%' 
AND YearGraduated = '2014';
```

However every other attempt at also getting the remaining FirstName, LastName, Email and HomeNo just aren't working.

Finally, I must create this as a view.

Comment: There is no link between Alumnus and AlumnusDeg, are there more tables?

Comment: It is not clear how this tables connected...

Comment: Here is the layout of all my tables http://s14.postimg.org/ruvlgfn9d/erd.png

Comment: Also, AlumniID are the same on both tables, AlumniID is the foreign key for Alumnus

Comment: If Tatiana's answer solved your problem, I'd suggest you mark it as accepted (by clicking the button with the checkmark icon next to it).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have done that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simple join, as I understand

```
SELECT * 
FROM AlumnusDeg ad JOIN Alumnus a on ad.alumniid=a.alumniid
WHERE DegreeName LIKE '%Computer Science%' 
AND YearGraduated = '2014';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ad.*, FirstName, LastName, Email, HomeNo
FROM alumnus a
INNER JOIN alumnusdeg ad ON a.AlumniID = ad.AlumniID
WHERE DegreeName LIKE '%Computer Science%' 
AND YearGraduated = '2014';
```